# Get results with wildcard

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am returning @ChangeStatus variable with 'Y', 'N', Null
and need to show data based on that however column has different string than variable

```
declare @ChangeStatus char(1) = 'Y'
select * from Application 
where Changes = (case when @ChangeStatus is null then Changes end)
and Changes like (case when @ChangeStatus = 'Y' then '%'end)
and Changes like (case when @ChangeStatus = 'N' then NULL end)
```

however no data shown

Comment: You would want to use OR not AND. But your case expressions are a bit off. The last one for example would never return anything. Not really clear how to help you though because it is a bit confusing what you are trying to do.

Comment: where (@ChangeStatus IS NULL  OR Changes = @ChangeStatus)

Comment: The logic seems to be something like `WHERE @ChangeStatus is null OR (@ChangeStatus = 'Y' AND Changes IS NOT NULL)`

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you want to use a combination of AND and OR with some brackets thrown in something like this:

```
select * 
from Application 
where 
    @ChangeStatus is null OR
    (@ChangeStatus = 'Y' AND Changes like '%') OR
    (@ChangeStatus = 'N' AND Changes is null)
```

Comment: @JOZO . . . This answers the question that you asked (and I would suggest accepting it).  If this is not the question you really wanted to ask, then ask a new question.